# My react app isn't working with socket.io-client. What should I do to fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, socket.io-client

i have a react app that's supposed to get data from the server and act accordingly. I am using socket.io-client and it isn't working when i call socket.on()

socket.js (client side):

```
import constants from '../constants';
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = openSocket();
const sockets = {
    mouseMove(payload) {
        socket.emit(constants.MOUSE_MOVE, payload);
    },
    mouseClick(payload) {
        socket.emit(constants.MOUSE_CLICK, payload);
    },
    getScreen(payload){
        socket.emit(constants.GET_SCREEN, payload);
        console.log("sent");
        socket.on(constants.SCREEN_DATA, ({imageData}) => {
            console.log("recieved screen data")
            };
        });
    }
}


export default sockets;
```

socket.js (server-side):

```
const constants = require('./constants');

function handleSocketEvents(socket, robot) {
    socket.on(constants.MOUSE_MOVE, ({ x, y, scroll }) => {
        if (!scroll) {
            const { x: X, y: Y } = robot.getMousePos();
            robot.moveMouse(x + X, y + Y);
        } else {
            y = y > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            robot.scrollMouse(0, y);
        }
    });

    socket.on(constants.MOUSE_CLICK, ({ button, double }) => {
        console.log('click', button);
        robot.mouseClick(button, double);
    });

    socket.on(constants.GET_SCREEN, ({output}) => {
        console.log("Received screen request");
        const size = robot.getScreenSize();
        const img = robot.screen.capture(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        const imgData = img.image.toString('base64');
        socket.emit(constants.SCREEN_DATA, imgData); // Emit the screen data back to the client
        console.log("Sent screen data");
    });
}

module.exports = handleSocketEvents;
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I tried looking at the documentation, but the openSocket() method has bad documentation and I got confused by it.